# A database with measurments of meteorological parameters at various altitudes

Tags: meteorology, open-data, database

I am a P.h.D student working on effects of Evaporation duct on radio propagation. Pandemic is successfully stopping me from obtaining my own measurements for my thesis, but I would like to compare the model I am working on with some real-world data. What I require is data for Atmospheric Pressure, temperature and relative humidity measured in one location at different altitudes. The University of Wyoming has published such a set of data (Available [here](http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html)):
[image]

While their data are perfectly fine, the fast ascend in altitudes where data are measured at is not ideal for me. What I require are the heights between 0 and 200 metres. Perhaps any of you know of a place where such data can be found?

Comment: https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/weather-balloon/integrated-global-radiosonde-archive Try that site

Comment: If you're located in America, you could try contact your local NWS office or closest one that launches radiosondes to see if they have more granular data that is culled for bandwidth management. Otherwise I don't think you're going to get much better data unless you get it yourself.

Comment: There are some high resolotion datasets in the UK CEDA archive - https://catalogue.ceda.ac.uk/uuid/c1e2240c353f8edeb98087e90e6d832e